# Copying data from one table to another with additional columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to put the data from one table to another table, with one constant number.

I have two tables,  Party and PartyRole(two columns PartyID and RoleID).

I want to put all the Id of Party table with constant Role i.e. 10 in PartyRole table.

Is this below query is right ?

```
INSERT INTO PartyRole (PArtyID, 10)
SELECT PArtyID
FROM Parties
```

Answer (score 2):

*Is this below query is right ?*

```
INSERT INTO PartyRole (PArtyID, 10)
SELECT PArtyID
FROM Parties
```

The answer is **NO**

Instead try the `Query`

```
INSERT INTO PartyRole
(PArtyID, RoleID)
SELECT 
PArtyID,
10
FROM Parties
```

Comment: **SELECT 
PArtyID,
10
FROM Parties** Just run this Query and see how many rows you are getting.

Comment: Since there are NO ID in Party table so how can you Insert it.

Comment: Query is right, I  selected wrong DB. thanks a lot.. sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: @user1650894 Consider either one with the Answer

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO PartyRole (PArtyID, RoleId)
SELECT PArtyID, 10
FROM Parties
```

Comment: When you run "SELECT PArtyID, 10 FROM Parties" on its own do you get any record back?